# ReportViewers overlay on refresh

Tags: asp.net, html, reporting-services, .net-4.0, reportviewer

I have an asp.net 4.0 web application that must display several reports one above another.
To achieve that I have placed several Reportviewers with SizeToReportContent set to true and AsyncRendering to false.

The thing is I don't want to refresh the whole page whenever I refresh just one report, that's why I use several reportviewers instead of just having one big report.

Now on the first time I go to the page it shows fine and the page is exactly how I want it to be.
But if I refresh one of the reports (by changing a parameter for example), its reportviewer shrinks during refresh, thus making the elements below go up in the page. When the refresh is finished, the reportviewer displays the report but the elements that went up do not go back down, and therefore the refreshed report and the one below overlay.

I tried putting them in separate divs or in table rows but it doesn't make a difference, however I'm not really good when it comes to html5/css 3 so there might be something to do there.

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks.

EDIT: I tried this in a brand new page, with no master page or css, and still get the issue, so my guess is that it's the reportviewers that hold the key to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so based on this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3209604/3767243), it seems that just adding a `Width="100%"` does the trick (I'm not really sure why though).

So this is what I end up with :

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" Height="100%" SizeToReportContent="true" AsyncRendering="false" >
    <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="MyURL" ReportPath="MyPath" />
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```